# How to correctly name these percentages?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've been researching some stuff about a certain game's probability systems and there are many cases when.... I can't really put it into words, so here's an example:

> **15% + 60% = 75%**

**15%** is the *base percentage*, and it is often called so in the description text. The **60%** in its own context is also called a *percentage* (but never with the *base* word). And the formula for the total chance is:

> Resulting Percentage = (Base + **X**) * Multiplier

Without **X** being explicitly called anything comprehensible.

What should the **X** thing be called?

Comment: Maybe I should be asking this on a math related site?

Comment: At the very least it can be called an *addend*

Comment: I would probably call it the _supplemental_ percentage.

Comment: Probabilities are only added when the events are entirely independent, so it could simply be called *the other percentage*.

Comment: What is the cause of the additional percentage? Does it depend on something? That's where I'd start with coming up with the word. If it's an RPG game it could be a *character skill bonus* or *class modifier*, or perhaps it's a *weapon modifier*. If the number doesn't change then it would be part of the base percentage – so why does the number change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by ghoppe, I've always seen that portion labeled as *modifier*.